# android - intent action namespace

Tags: android, android-intent

Android's intent [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) states that :

> action must be in a namespace because Intents are used globally in the system

Does this namespace concept just imply that if I don't use, for e.g., my app's package name as a prefix for a custom action name, then it may conflict with the action name for a different app, so when some app is using intent, it may start the wrong component because of my name conflict. Is there any more detail that needs to be worried about when it comes to namespace in intents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this namespace concept just imply that if I don't use, for e.g., my app's package name as a prefix for a custom action name, then it may conflict with the action name for a different app, so when some app is using intent, it may start the wrong component because of my name conflict.

More or less.

> Is there any more detail that needs to be worried about when it comes to namespace in intents ?

It is unlikely that creating a custom action is the right solution for whatever problem that you are solve. One use case for it is if you are going to try to convince third-party developers to specifically invoke one of your activities, perhaps as part of an SDK that you are creating for such developers. This is well within reason, just unlikely. Another use case would be if you have a suite of apps that you were trying to inter-link at specific spots. This is somewhat more probable, but it becomes a bit of a problem to do well -- by default, any app in the system will be able to start that activity if they so chose, and securing that can get tricky.

Note that you neither want nor need an action string of any sort for activities that are private to your app. That's because you neither want nor need an `<intent-filter>` for activities that are private to your app. Just use explicit `Intent`s to invoke such activities.